FluentDataGrid content disappearing after clicking anywhere on the data grid
I am working on a Blazor component that should dynamically determine and display the columns of a FluentDataGrid. My approach is similar to that of Vaclav Elias for QuickGrids (see feature request and QuickGridToolkit), but - hopefully - a bit more generic.
So far, my approach seems to work. However, when I click anywhere on the data grid, the rows disappear, leaving only the horizontal borders between the rows (screenshots at the end of this post). How can I prevent this from happening?
Below is the code for a minimalistic example of my implementation.
Person.cs:
This is the model class I use in this example.
public class Person
{
    public required int ID { get; set; }
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public DateOnly? Birthday { get; set; }
    public bool Flag
    {
        get { return (ID % 2) == 0; }
        set { }
    }
}

ColumnInfo.cs
Used to determine the parameters of a given PropertyColumn. For simplicity, I only handle the parameters Property and Title.
public class ColumnInfo<TGridItem>
{
    public ColumnInfo(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        _propertyInfo = propertyInfo;
        // Build the Lambda-Expression used for PropertyColumn.Property 
        // parameter and specify the parameter type.
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TGridItem), "p");
        Expression body = parameter;
        body = Expression.Property(body, propertyInfo);
        Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TGridItem), _propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        _property = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, body, parameter);
        _title = _propertyInfo.Name;
    }
    private readonly PropertyInfo _propertyInfo;
    public Type PropertyType
    {
        get => _propertyInfo.PropertyType;
    }
    private readonly LambdaExpression _property;

    public LambdaExpression Property
    {
        get => _property;
    }
    private readonly string _title;

    public string Title
    {
        get => _title;
    }
    public ColumnBase<TGridItem>? Instance { get; set; }
}

DynamicGridColumns.razor
This is my "magic" component that populates the grid columns.
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Reflection
@using Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components
@typeparam TGridItem

@if (_columnInfos != null && _columnInfos.Count > 0)
{
    @foreach (var ci in _columnInfos)
    {
        @RenderColumn(ci)
    }
}

@code {
    private List<ColumnInfo<TGridItem>>? _columnInfos;

    private RenderFragment RenderColumn(ColumnInfo<TGridItem> info)
    {
        return new RenderFragment(builder =>
        {
            Type columnType = typeof(PropertyColumn<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TGridItem), info.PropertyType);
            builder.OpenComponent(0, columnType);
            builder.AddComponentParameter(1, "Property", info.Property);
            builder.AddComponentParameter(2, "Title", info.Title);

            builder.AddComponentReferenceCapture(3, instance =>
            {
                info.Instance = instance as ColumnBase<TGridItem>;
            });

            builder.CloseComponent();
        });
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _columnInfos = typeof(TGridItem)
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(p => new ColumnInfo<TGridItem>(p))
            .ToList();
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}

which leads to the final result:
PersonsDataGrid.razor
@using Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components

<h3>Persons</h3>

<FluentDataGrid TGridItem="Person" Items="_data" ItemKey="@(i => i.ID)">
    <DynamicGridColumns />
</FluentDataGrid>

@code {
    private IQueryable<Person>? _data;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _data = Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
            .Select(i => new Person() { ID = i, Name = $"Name {i}", Birthday = new DateOnly(2000 + i, i, i) })
            .AsQueryable();
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

}

Screenshots
Before click (as expected)
Grid before clicking
After click
Grid after click
